# Using Django and PHP in Nginx

Tags: php, django, nginx

I'm using Django in a Vhost and PHP in another, now I want to make one file with the two things, a part for Django and another for PHP.

I've read this question but it's not helping me.
[How to run django and wordpress on NGINX server using same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581246/how-to-run-django-and-wordpress-on-nginx-server-using-same-domain?rq=1)
this one didn't help either 
[How can I configure nginx to serve a Django app and a Wordpress site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725133/how-can-i-configure-nginx-to-serve-a-django-app-and-a-wordpress-site)

This is part of what I have in the PHP config:

```
root /var/www/agendav/web/public;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php;

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
```

This is the full Django part:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock;
}

root /path/to/project/folder;
charset     utf-8;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
if ($allowed_country = no) {
    return 444;
}

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   
# Django media
location /media  {
    alias /path/to/mysite/media/;  
}

location /static {
    alias /path/to/mysite/static/; 
}

location ~ /cal/.*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/agendav/web/public;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/login  =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  pass;
    include     /path/to/uwsgi_params; 
}
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow all;
}
```

And I'm trying to add this to the other conf file (that's already working)

```
location ~ /cal/.*\.php$ {
    root /var/www/agendav/web/public;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/login  =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

for what I've read, that should do, but all I've getting is a 404 error, or a blank page and no readings in the nginx log or even in the agendav(the app in PHP) ones.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is django configuration part ?

Comment: There you go @sideffect I added the (almost) full config file, only left out the part of ports, ssl and that kind of thing.

Comment: you are getting django uwsgi logs ? you checked ??

Comment: Ok, it was my fault, I didn't check properly everything... With that config I was getting logs in the uwsgi logs, that's made me think that the location was not ok and I've changed it, after a few changes I've got a location block that go to my PHP app when I have something.php in my URL, next is try to focus only in what has /cal/ in the url and a .php file.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you post your final configuration?